# Third highest used programming language PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to find the inventor of the third most used programming language by the teams on the most populated floor

I've tried this so far, but i'm getting an error.

Tried to fix it but seems i can't

```
select * from (select count(engineer_programming_languages.programming_language), DENSE_RANK() OVER 
(ODER BY count(engineer_programming_languages.programming_language_id DESC) as rk ) 
from engineer_programming_languages ) as t 
join engineer_programming_languages on engineer_programming_languages.programming_language_id
 = programming_languages.id 
join programming_languages where t = 3;
```

Tables:

```
sqlhunt_development=# \d programming_languages
                                       Table "public.programming_languages"
    Column     |            Type             |                             Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                      | not null default nextval('programming_languages_id_seq'::regclass)
 name          | character varying           |
 category      | character varying           |
 date_of_birth | integer                     |
 inventor      | character varying           |
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "programming_languages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "engineer_programming_languages" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_888c6565a8" FOREIGN KEY (programming_language_id) REFERENCES programming_languages(id)

sqlhunt_development=# \d engineer_programming_languages
                                            Table "public.engineer_programming_languages"
         Column          |            Type             |                                  Modifiers
-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                      | bigint                      | not null default nextval('engineer_programming_languages_id_seq'::regclass)
 proficency              | character varying           |
 repositories            | integer                     |
 engineer_id             | bigint                      |
 programming_language_id | bigint                      |
 created_at              | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at              | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "engineer_programming_languages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_engineer_programming_languages_on_engineer_id" btree (engineer_id)
    "index_engineer_programming_languages_on_programming_language_id" btree (programming_language_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_3a4377ed71" FOREIGN KEY (engineer_id) REFERENCES engineers(id)
    "fk_rails_888c6565a8" FOREIGN KEY (programming_language_id) REFERENCES programming_languages(id)

sqlhunt_development=# \d teams
                                        Table "public.teams"
      Column      |            Type             |                     Modifiers
------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id               | bigint                      | not null default nextval('teams_id_seq'::regclass)
 name             | character varying           |
 floor            | integer                     |
 features_shipped | integer                     |
 current_bugs     | integer                     |
 created_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "teams_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "engineers" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5c44cd68ac" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id)

sqlhunt_development=# \d engineers
                                     Table "public.engineers"
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('engineers_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name | character varying           |
 last_name  | character varying           |
 age        | integer                     |
 email      | character varying           |
 country_id | bigint                      |
 team_id    | bigint                      |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "engineers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_engineers_on_country_id" btree (country_id)
    "index_engineers_on_team_id" btree (team_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_48c685314b" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
    "fk_rails_5c44cd68ac" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "bookshelves" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_13dec3ee94" FOREIGN KEY (engineer_id) REFERENCES engineers(id)
    TABLE "engineer_programming_languages" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_3a4377ed71" FOREIGN KEY (engineer_id) REFERENCES engineers(id)
```

You can see in there that tables don't have that much keys that i can follow to achieve the result and my ideas has ran out already :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you can use `dense_rank()` as follows:

```
select programming_language_id
from (
    select
        programming_language_id,
        dense_rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from engineer_programming_languages
    group by programming_language_id
) t
where rn = 3
```

Comment: I need to Find the inventor of the third most used programming language by the teams on the most populated floor. In the question edit the tables itself with their relationships